# iforgot keeps sending emails to icloud.com address which I'm trying to recover in the first place

Tags: icloud, email, password

This is silly beyond words. I'm trying to restore my apple account with email at icloud.com via `iforgot.apple.com`. After they verify my phone number and I enter the code, they say that another confirmation code was sent to my icloud.com email which I'm trying to recover in the first place!

> We will contact you shortly, at snipsnip@icloud.com, to let you know when your waiting period will be over. Apple Support cannot help to reduce your waiting period.

I tried several times, same result. How do I proceed from this dead loop?

Comment: Having the account and using that same account for the recovery mail seems to be the error. I set recoery email addresses to different accounts.

Comment: @SolarMike I won't argue about that, I created this account for my child a while ago, and I now I wouldn't make this mistake. However, this was the Apple recommended approach when setting up a new account at the time, Apple creates an email for you, and lets you use it. It should be a common issue, I guess.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they've always recommended using a separate email for recovery. Otherwise you're kind of sawing at the branch you're sitting on, in an emergency.

Comment: @Tetsujin Maybe, it was a long time ago. But it's irrelevant now, in the end they allowed me to do it. What matters now, is that their recovery procedure clearly breaks with such a simple case.

Comment: I'm glad they gave you a pass on it. I honestly don't remember when the advice may have started, been doing this long enough to forget;) - I've flipped from one Apple account to another as they years have gone by. I still have a mac.com from the 90s [dormant], one from from 20 years ago under my own domain name from when iTunes went online & a me.com [eventually subsumed to icloud.com, so I have both those addresses now simultaneously on the same account] from when that started, both confusingly still active - one buys things, the other syncs things. One day, they'll allow merging…

Comment: If you provided an icloud email, you have to go to iforgot.apple.com to get the resolution(the waiting time to recover your account)
Thanks!